# Searchbar filtering issue

Tags: ios, swift4, uisearchbar

Im new to the swift, I am trying to filter name from an array using the search bar in console am getting what I entered in the search bar but filtering with predicate im not getting filtered name...please can anyone help in this issue

```
var caseListOfBooker:[CaseDetails]=[]

var searchString:String=""

var filteredString = [String]()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            print("searchText \(searchText)")

            searchString = searchText
            updateSearchResults()
            tableview.reloadData()
        }
        func updateSearchResults(){

        filteredString.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)

        let array = self.caseListOfBooker.filter{$0.person_of_interest.contains(searchString)}
            print(array)

                    if let list=array as? [String]{
                        filteredString=list
                    }


            print(filteredString)

            tableview.reloadData()



    }


extension SearchPOIVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if filteredString != []{

            return filteredString.count
        }
        else
        {
            if searchString != "[]" {
                return caseListOfBooker.count
            }else {
                return 0
            }
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80.00
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:POIProfileDetailsCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "POIProfileDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! POIProfileDetailsCell
        if filteredString != []{

            cell.poiName.text = filteredString[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }else{

            if searchString != "[]"{
                 cell.poiName.text = self.caseListOfBooker[indexPath.row].person_of_interest

            }
            return cell

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to filter custom classes is to use the **same** type for the data source array **and** the filtered array

```
var caseListOfBooker = [CaseDetails]()
var filteredBooker = [CaseDetails]()
```

Add a property `isFiltering` which is set to true when the search text is not empty

```
var isFiltering = false
```

and delete `searchString` and `filteredString`

```
var searchString:String=""
var filteredString = [String]()
```

In `updateSearchResults` filter the data source array (with native Swift functions), set `isFiltering` accordingly and reload the table view

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("searchText \(searchText)")
    updateSearchResults(searchText: searchText)
}

func updateSearchResults(searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredBooker.removeAll()
        isFiltering = false
    } else {
        filteredBooker = caseListOfBooker.filter{$0.person_of_interest.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
        isFiltering = true
    }
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

In the table view data source methods display the data depending on `isFiltering`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isFiltering ? filteredBooker.count : caseListOfBooker.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "POIProfileDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! POIProfileDetailsCell
    let booker = isFiltering ? filteredBooker[indexPath.row] : caseListOfBooker[indexPath.row]
    cell.poiName.text = booker.person_of_interest
}
```

Comment: Pass the `indexPath` as `sender`, implement `prepare(for segue` and hand over the item at indexPath

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409535/get-cell-index-from-tableviewcell/41410245#41410245 And don't add information regarding the question in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56127669/edit) the question.

Comment: When you click on a cell while filtering you have to get the item from the `filteredBooker` array rather than from `caseListOfBooker` like in `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow`.

Comment: * Sigh * Please learn to understand the code. You have to add the same `isFiltering – ? – :` expression like in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = self.caseListOfBooker.filter{$0.person_of_interest.contains(searchString)}
```

You are getting array of `CaseDetails` objects and trying to cast to array of `String`

It fails. You need to get string values from the `CaseDetails` object and join them

Use

```
filteredString = array.map { $0.person_of_interest }
```

Or

```
for caseDetail in array {
    filteredString.append(caseDetail.person_of_interest)
}
```

Instead of

```
if let list = array as? [String]{
    filteredString=list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchPredicate = NSPredicate()
searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self CONTAINS[C] %@", your_searching_text)        
let Final_Search_array = (Your_Array).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer